# C/C++ debugger does not work on Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio-3.0, android-debug

**Dual debugging (C/C++ and Java) works normally in Android Studio 2.3.3** with *minSdkVersion: 22*, *targetSdkVersion/compileSdkVersion: 26*.

When I update to **Android Studio 3.0.1**, then **Java debugger is normal** but **C/C++ debugger does not work**. I test it separately between *Java and C/C++ debugger* to find out which debugger is not working.

The problem is **C/C++ debugger does not work** on Android Studio 3.0.1. An error occurred like this:

> failed to get reply to handshake packet
>   com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriverException:
>   failed to get reply to handshake packet   at
>   com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriver$ThrowIfNotValid.throwIfNeeded(LLDBDriver.java:143)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.connectPlatform(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:308)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.loadForLaunch(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:158)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.loadForAttach(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:199)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.ndk.run.AndroidNativeAppDebugProcess.prepareTarget(AndroidNativeAppDebugProcess.java:98)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.ndk.run.AndroidNativeDebugProcess.doStart(AndroidNativeDebugProcess.java:113)
>     at
>   com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$3.run(CidrDebugProcess.java:307)
>     at
>   com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$MyCommandProcessor.consume(CidrDebugProcess.java:724)
>     at
>   com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$MyCommandProcessor.consume(CidrDebugProcess.java:714)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$null$0(QueueProcessor.java:106)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:223)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$wrappingProcessor$1(QueueProcessor.java:106)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$null$2(QueueProcessor.java:203)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:223)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$startProcessing$3(QueueProcessor.java:203)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having dual debugging issue also with Android Studio 3.1. Try using different Emulator SDK level. I could not use dual debugging with SDK 16 emulator. It only worked for me using SDK 24 emulator.

Answer (score 2):

I used AVD Pixel 2 XL API 22 - x86 - Google API (can be rooted) and got the same problem "failed to get reply to handshake packet", with the log:

```
Launching 'setMeasurement() (1)' on Pixel 2 XL API 22 - x86 - Google API 
Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug true -e \
    class 'com.my.package.MyClassTest#setMeasurement' \
    com.my.package.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

Waiting for application to come online: com.my.package | com.my.package.test
...
Waiting for application to come online: com.my.package | com.my.package.test

Connecting to com.my.package.test
Now Launching Native Debug Session

$ adb shell cat /data/local/tmp/lldb-server \
    | sh -c 'cat > /data/data/com.my.package/lldb/bin/lldb-server
    \ && chmod 700 /data/data/com.my.package/lldb/bin/lldb-server'

$ adb shell cat /data/local/tmp/start_lldb_server.sh \
    | sh -c 'cat > /data/data/com.my.package/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh \
    && chmod 700 /data/data/com.my.package/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh'

Starting LLDB server:
failed to get reply to handshake packet
```

So I tried to repeat the commands (adb shell + locally running commands) - and last two adb shell commands failed. Inspecting the phone file directories structure I found out:

1. in adb command for setup ldb-server the target path is wrong, it is "/data/data/com.my.package" and APK is located in /data/app/com.my.package-2 (suffix -2 is probably dynamically created)
2. folder .../lldb/bin/ does not exists too
3. the adb command obviously failed since the folders and files were not copied/setup on the emulator. This brings the other issue I submitted: ["Android Studio C++ Debugger startup silently ignores phone LLDB setup critical issues"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140396458)

The workaround that worked for me was to create the (wrong?) target folder before the setup:

```
adb shell
mkdir -p /data/data/com.my.package/lldb/bin
```

The problem is reported as [Android Studio C++ Debugger uses wrong paths on phone in LLDB setup procedure causing: failed to get reply to handshake packet](https://issuetracker.google.com/140369526)

Answer (score 1):

Simple uninstall and install helps me.

```
adb uninstall com.your.package
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `adb uninstall` with your package name. I faced this issue and solved it using this command.